# Do Chrome and Firefox show Inspect / Inspect Element in their context menus by default?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html

I'm writing some instructions on how to work around a broken modal on Duolingo by deleting some HTML. I'm trying to write it so non-techy people can follow along.

On Safari I found I had to go to Preferences > Advanced and enable developer tools for the "Inspect" context menu item to start appearing.

What about Chrome and Firefox? I've used both Chrome and Firefox for so long that I can't remember if I enabled developer tools at some point or, they just have Inspect / Inspect Element by default. I see that I continue to have this option in Incognito Mode *and* after signing out of my Chrome browser account, but I'm not confident that there isn't some local setting affecting this.

Does someone know *for sure* if a brand new installation of Chrome and Firefox would still have the Inspect / Inspect Element context menu item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Inspect/Inspect Element is available by default in context menu of Chrome/firefox.
BY Default Developer tools are not enabled until you Open Developer tools from Menu or Shortcut. As you click on inspect element Browser enables the Developer Tools.

Comment: Both answers were good but it was interesting to learn that Developer Mode can be turned on by first entrance into Inspect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a test, I reset Firefox to check if the Inspect Element will appear on the context menu or not. After resetting it, Inspect Element was present on the context menu even in Incognito mode.

In Chrome, Developer mode was off; however Inspect appeared on the context menu in both "Normal" and Incognito mode.

It seems that Inspect/Inspect Element are shown on the context menu by default.